# How to translate Japanese response page to English in Python Selenuim

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

How to translate Japanese response page to English in Python Selenium. As i need to scrape a Japanese site, i could'nt even extract a single text from the site because all are in Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome has a built in feature that lets you translate an entire page into your language. What you could do is set the language in the application to, say, English, go to the site in Chrome and auto translate back in to your language. However this could be tricky and may require something like [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb?hl=en](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb?hl=en%20google%20chrome) google chrome extension to fulfill your requirement. You can automate this utility using autoit.

To add an extension for chrome driver, please refer to those links:

[Create .CRX file](http://www.helloselenium.com/2014/09/how-to-create-crx-file-from-already.html) and [Add extension to Chrome WebDriver](http://www.helloselenium.com/2014/09/how-to-add-extension-to-google-chrome.html)

A possible workaround could be if you can utilize something like these custom configs. Those Python examples, should help :

Firefox:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('intl.accept_languages', 'es')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Chrome:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option( "prefs", {'--lang': 'es'})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: **In [283]: FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();**  I got an error >> `File "<ipython-input-283-e94832a64279>", line 1
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` Pls specify me if i need to do something before executing those commands since am a beginner

Comment: I am using firefox and i tried your suggestion but it did'nt worked. I need to translate a Japanese website using selenuim